# VSCode - Highlighting a tag quickly with keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-code

silly VS Code question!

In Sublime and other text editors I often highlight an end-tag to cut it or move it etc, using `opt + shift + back-arrow` (MacOS). For some reason, in VS Code it always jumps to highlight not only the tag but also the character that comes before the tag and it drive me crazy.

See gif for example:

[image]

When I try to highlight the `</h2>` tag, it always grabs the `>` from the `<small>` tag too etc.

Is there a way to stop this behaviour, or an alternate way to highlight an end tag I don't know?

Comment: I know there are some extensions that can add your sublime, atom, etc shortcut to VS code. did you try them?

Comment: @MahdiMahmoodian I tried, but it didn't help, it's not a shortcut problem, the shortcut is the same across MacOS, but VSCode seems to handle it a bit weirdly.

Comment: does VSC jump to word boundaries using this command, and all consecutive non alphabet characters are jumped in one go.

Comment: Seems like a bug, the word separators aren't being respected properly.  You should file it.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, I've done so here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88848

Answer (score 1):

You can highlight each letter with "shift + R/L arrow". So if you highlight to the ">" letter then you can go one step to the right with "shift + right arrow".

Comment: I know you can do that, it's just not ideal. Seems like a really illogical choice from the VSCode team.